# I want to implement object array with variable.im getting error "expression must be a constant value"

Tags: c++, syntax-error, solution

```
Int size;  //size is variable
cout<<"enter size";
cin>>size;
Inventory p[size];
/*Inventory is a class.p is an 
 object of inventory class.*/
```

I want to implement array object with size variable but I'm getting error "expression mush have a constant value"

Comment: This is correct. In `c++` the size of an array must be a compile time constant. The proper solution in `c++` is to use a `std::vector` for your dynamically sized array.

Comment: You try to define a [variable-length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). Those aren't part of the C++ language. Use `std::vector` instead.